# Merging all workbooks in folder and moving to sub folder

Tags: excel, vba

I've read multiple Subs on here but for some reason I can't get my code nailed down.
I've got 3 folders with multiple workbooks in them.
I need to open my default template workbook, and then copy the data from sheet one of each workbook in the current folder to sheet one of the template, then move those files to a sub-folder called "archive"
After that I need to create one master workbook combining the data of those 3 sub-workbooks.

I'm using Excel 2016. I'm using an array to specify the three main folders. Example

`MyTeam(1) = Alpha`

`MyTeam(2) = Beta`

So the path would be something like `C:\MyFolder\" & MyTeam(i) & "\*.xlxs`

I'd post my code but really it is totally borked.
I'm Using a Userform/CommandButton to execute the code. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I've seen examples of people saying to load all the files into an array. But when trying to use the code examples it hasn't been successful on my end. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I ended up going a different route. Decided to just open/close the main two files at the time my code exports the data. That way multi-users could use it at the same time but not cause a conflict. Seems to work like a charm